# My table is overflowing to the second text column

Tags: tables

[image]

I have used this code.

```
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}
    \captionof{table}{GA parameters}\label{title}
     \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}||p{4cm}||p{5cm}||p{4cm}|}
     \hline
     %\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Parameter of GA} \\
     \hline
     Technique         &  Aim    & distinctive attribute & Limitations \\
     \hline
     Maximum iteration & Total result&   house hold appliance       &      porpery        \\
     Population size   & &          &                  \\
     $P_{c}$           &\&          &                   \\
     $P_{m}$           &\rmfamily  0.1&          &                     \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also, your column specification indicate at least 16 cm of space for the table. it seems a bit much to me

Comment: The code is still not compilable

Comment: Dear moriambar! I have corrected my question according to your suggestion.

Comment: It has no documentclass still, but the code you posted certainly cannot produce a `200` in the aim column, since there's no `200` in your code

Comment: Kindly help me out as I am going through this issue.

Comment: Dear moria! I got you but issue is actually seen that my table comes on to the paragraph how do I adjust that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your table is wider than the width of one column, it spans the two columns. You can use the starred version of `table*` and use whatever column specifications you need like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}\centering
\caption{GA parameters}\label{title}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{4cm}p{5cm}p{4cm}}
 \toprule
 Technique         & Aim & distinctive attribute & Limitations \\ \midrule
 Maximum iteration & 200 & house hold appliance  & porpery     \\
 Population size   & 30  &                       &             \\
 $P_{c}$           & 0.9 &                       &             \\
 $P_{m}$           & 0.1 &                       &             \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Dear Aboammar!! Thanks for your help. But I want this big table i.e, table from to right of the page but my text in there.

Comment: @Shane: Please see my edit!

Comment: Aboammar if I want to adjust width of my desire how I do that i.e, in tabular case I do like with double column line {|p{3cm}||p{4cm}||p{5cm}||p{4cm}|}.

Comment: Yes, you can do the same, remove `tabularx` and put `tabular` and remove all vertical bars. See my re-edit!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, not knowing your setup, but deducing it from the text, I assume you have a two column environment/documentclass, since it's the only way I can reproduce your problem.

This is a suggestion for correcting the code, i.e. using the `table*` environment in order to typeset the table. I took the liberty of removing all of the extra separators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{GA parameters}\label{title}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
Technique&Aim&distinctive attribute &limitations\\
\midrule
Maximum iteration & 300 &household appliance&porpery\\
Population size& 30& & \\
$P_{c}$& 0.9& & \\
$P_{m}$&0.1& & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[50-76]

\section{sss}

\lipsum[10-55]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh Moria thanks you are right I guess!! But I got an error to adjust so many things as I am a beginner in latex.

Comment: @Shane we've all been beginners. Take one step at a time, and browse around the most asked/most voted questions on this website to find advice

Comment: Really Thank you Moria! Keep in touch me and keep guide me.